# .html not working as intended

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('#clicker').click(function () {
 collegeArray = ["Harvard", "Yale", "Princeton"];
 alert(collegeArray.length);
 for (var i = 0; i < collegeArray.length; i++) {
     var divIdName = 'college' + i + 'Div'; //manuplating name of each div generated dynamically
     var newdiv = document.createElement('div')
     .setAttribute('id', divIdName) //setting the name of each div created dynamically
     .html('<p>' + collegeArray.toString() + '</p>')
     appendTo($(#'survey'));
 }
});
```

The above code should append html everytime the clicker button is pressed, but it's not working. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here

http://jsfiddle.net/HvJnH/19/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to use jQuery methods on a raw DOM element.

```
var newdiv = $('<div/>')
  .prop('id', divIdName) //setting the name of each div created dynamically
  .html('<p>' + collegeArray.toString() + '</p>')
  .appendTo($(#'survey'));
```

Alternatively:

```
var newdiv = $('<div/>', {
  id: divIdName,
  html: '<p>' + collegeArray.toString() + '</p>'
}).appendTo('#survey');
```

*edit* — also, as Shmiddty points out in a comment, you should definitely not re-use "id" values on multiple elements. Use the "class" property if you want to categorize elements for some purpose, or make up new "id" values with a counter or something.

Comment: You should also mention how repeating the same ID is bad. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your # is outside your quotes on your survey selector.

you have `$(#'survey')` when you should have `$('#survey')`

Also, you're mixing jQuery functions with regular javascript functions and elements.

Answer (score 1):

You had several issues, including using jQuery methods on a plain JS element and putting a `#` outside quotes. Try this:

```
$('#clicker').click(function () {
    collegeArray = ["Harvard", "Yale", "Princeton"];
    for (var i = 0; i < collegeArray.length; i++) {
        var divIdName = 'college' + i + 'Div'; //manuplating name of each div generated dynamically
        var newdiv = $('<div></div>', {
            id: divIdName
        })
            .html('<p>' + collegeArray.toString() + '</p>')
            .appendTo($('#survey'));
    }
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/HvJnH/22/)

Answer (score 1):

Some corrections and it may work:

```
$('#clicker').click(function () {
    var collegeArray = ["Harvard", "Yale", "Princeton"];
    for (var i = 0; i < collegeArray.length; i++) {
        var divIdName = 'college' + i + 'Div';
        var newDiv = $("<div/>")
            .attr("id", divIdName)
            .html('<p>' + collegeArray[i] + '</p>');

        $("#survey").append(newDiv);
    }
});
```

Comment: +1 For noticing that the OP probably wants each "College" in a separate div.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following..Its working

```
 $('#clicker').click(function () {
   collegeArray = ["Harvard", "Yale", "Princeton"];

     for (var i = 0; i < collegeArray.length; i++) {
         var divIdName = 'college' + i + 'Div'; 
          $('<div></div>').attr('id', divIdName).html('<p>' + collegeArray.toString() + '</p>').appendTo($('#survey'));
     }
 });
```